# Plotting a histogram with ggplot2 when the magnitude of data is large

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have this following data frame, `df` for which I desire to plot a histogram.

```
     x
1   -28313937
2   -218616099
3   -18406124
4   20307666
5   31985283
6   41429217
7   46488567
8   47690792
9   51127321
10  53168291
11  55247883
12  -49200409
13  33398814
14  36198419
15  42765257
16  45857195
17  43870899
18  50557988
19  49574516
20  52317786
21  50769743
```

I use the following piece of code for plotting the histogram,

```
R_hist <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth=.5, colour="black", fill="white") + 
geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(x, na.rm=T)), color="violet", linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

When I tried to call the object R_hist, I get an **Error : cannot allocate vector of size 4.1 Gb
In addition: Warning messages: 
1: In seq.default(round_any(range[1], size, floor), round_any(range[2],  :
  Reached total allocation of 4021Mb: see help(memory.size)**

Could someone please let me know why the histogram is not being plotted as it should here

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible?

Comment: You're trying to plot a bar for every value between `-218616099` and `55247883` in 0.5 increments... do you want 21 bars with a height indicated in `x`?  ... FWIW, that is a vector of 500 million values, which winds up being too large to allocate.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Reproducible in what sense? I tried using a different name for the graph object still got the same error though

Comment: @Justin Thanks for your comment. Yes, indeed I want 21 bars with height indicated in x

Comment: Give us the data and the code you use to plot. Here are some tips on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @RomanLuštrik see my answer for a method to grab the data provided.

Comment: @Justin I wanted it to be pedagogical. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as indicated in the comments, you're trying to plot a histogram with a bar from the min to max value in `df$x`.

Instead, use `geom_bar` and `stat='identity'`:

```
# grab the data provied
df <- read.table('clipboard')

# switch the names cause it'll bug me
df$y <- df$x
df$x <- row.names(df)

# plot using some identifier (row.names in this case)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_bar(stat='
```

Comment: How can I make a boxplot for this data in ggplot excluding the negative values. `boxplot(df)` plots the entire data

Comment: @Amm I strongly encourage you to read a few intro to R guides.  Specifically you want to look into subsetting.  However, in this instance, you would use `boxplot(df[df$x>0,])`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will look into subsetting.

Answer (score 0):

Loading large datasets in R is usually inefficient; I'd recommend looking at [DuckDB](https://duckdb.org) (it has an R connector).

DuckDB allows you to query large datasets in several formats (e.g., CSV, Parquet) using SQL, so you don't have memory issues. You can use it to compute the height of the histogram bins pretty efficiently, then use R to plot it (as opposed to loading the entire dataset into R).

Here's a snippet you can use in DuckDB to compute bins and bin heights, given a bin size:

```sql
select
  floor(COLUMN/BIN_SIZE)*BIN_SIZE,
  count(*) as count
from "path/to/file.parquet"
group by 1
order by 1;
```